# Optimizing time complexity - Quinn McClusky

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I implemented Quinn McClusky logic minimization and now trying to optimize this piece of code:

```
public int[] differsMaxOneChar(String a, String b) {
    debug.println("Comparing " + a + " to " + b);
    int[] returnValue = {1, 0};
    boolean differs = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (!(a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(i))) {
            if (differs) {
                returnValue[0] = 0;
                break;
            } else {
                differs = true;
                returnValue[1] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Any help on that would be very much appreciated.

String a and b have always the same length. Method checks if they differ in exactly one position. a and b consist of '0, '1' and 'X'. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of O time complexity, you've achieved O(n), which is as good as possible for this problem.
There are only small ways (that don't effect O complexity) that you could optimize, such as storing the length of a as a variable (instead of recalculating it on each iteration.)

Also, your function name suggests you're checking to see if it differs by at most one character, but in your description you say "exactly one" position. Which is it you're trying to do?